# Calculating group average, then lagging based on group

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working on my skills in R. I'd like to solve this problem using the `dplyr` package, if possible.

I have a dataset of fantasy football statistics. Each record is a player's statistics for one game (week) of a season, including the fantasy football points that player was worth that week.

Here's a snippet of the data I'm working with:

```
           Player  Week  year Fantasy.Points Avg.Fantasy.Ponts
 1 Aaron Hernandez     1  2011           16.3          9.678571
 2 Aaron Hernandez     2  2011           12.2          9.678571
 3 Aaron Hernandez     5  2011            5.6          9.678571
 4 Aaron Hernandez     6  2011           10.8          9.678571
 5 Aaron Hernandez     8  2011            7.1          9.678571
 6 Aaron Hernandez     9  2011            9.5          9.678571
 7 Aaron Hernandez    10  2011            4.1          9.678571
 8 Aaron Hernandez    11  2011            4.4          9.678571
 9 Aaron Hernandez    12  2011            6.2          9.678571
10 Aaron Hernandez    13  2011            4.3          9.678571
11 Aaron Hernandez    14  2011            8.4          9.678571
12 Aaron Hernandez    15  2011           20.5          9.678571
13 Aaron Hernandez    16  2011            3.7          9.678571
14 Aaron Hernandez    17  2011           22.4          9.678571
15 Aaron Hernandez     1  2012           12.4          8.755556
16 Aaron Hernandez     6  2012            9.0          8.755556
17 Aaron Hernandez     7  2012            5.4          8.755556
18 Aaron Hernandez    12  2012            3.6          8.755556
19 Aaron Hernandez    13  2012            9.7          8.755556
20 Aaron Hernandez    14  2012           17.8          8.755556
```

The field `Avg.Fantasy.Points` is the average number of points that player was worth *over the year in that record.* For example, Aaron Hernandez was worth an average of 9.678571 points over the 2011 season, and 8.755556 points over the 2012 season.

I'm interested in computing a column for the average number of points a player was worth *in the previous year*. In the example above, a record for Aaron Hernandez in the year 2012 should show that the previous year had an average of 9.68571 points.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround solution, similar to a subquery in SQL.

Say `df_te` is the dataframe from the snippet above:

```
df_te %>%
    left_join(
       mutate(next.year = year + 1) %>%    #add a column for the next year
       group_by(Player, year) %>%
       mutate(Previous.Avg.Fantasy.Points = first(Avg.Fantasy.Points) %>%   #Copy of 'Avg.Fantasy.Points' column, with the name I'd like to have for new column
       filter(row_number() == 1) %>%  #Only keep one row per player/year group to avoid duplication upon join
       select(Player, next.year, Previous.Avg.Fantasy.Points)   #keep only columns I'd like to join in
    by = c("Player" = "Player", "year" = "next.year")  #By joining 'year' on LHS table with 'next.year' on RHS table, can get the previous year's average points.     
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the `dplyr` package, I want to introduce the use of `lag` function. It can shift the values for a given number of rows. The default is 1. The last line `select(c(colnames(dt), "Pre.Avg.Fantasy.Ponts"))` is just for adjusting the order of the columns. `dt2` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  group_by(Player, year) %>%
  summarise(Avg.Fantasy.Ponts = first(Avg.Fantasy.Ponts)) %>%
  mutate(Pre.Avg.Fantasy.Ponts = lag(Avg.Fantasy.Ponts)) %>%
  select(-Avg.Fantasy.Ponts) %>%
  right_join(dt, by = c("Player", "year")) %>%
  select(c(colnames(dt), "Pre.Avg.Fantasy.Ponts"))
```

Data

```
dt <- read.table(text = "          Player  Week  year Fantasy.Points Avg.Fantasy.Ponts
 1 'Aaron Hernandez'     1  2011           16.3          9.678571
                 2 'Aaron Hernandez'     2  2011           12.2          9.678571
                 3 'Aaron Hernandez'     5  2011            5.6          9.678571
                 4 'Aaron Hernandez'     6  2011           10.8          9.678571
                 5 'Aaron Hernandez'     8  2011            7.1          9.678571
                 6 'Aaron Hernandez'     9  2011            9.5          9.678571
                 7 'Aaron Hernandez'    10  2011            4.1          9.678571
                 8 'Aaron Hernandez'    11  2011            4.4          9.678571
                 9 'Aaron Hernandez'    12  2011            6.2          9.678571
                 10 'Aaron Hernandez'    13  2011            4.3          9.678571
                 11 'Aaron Hernandez'    14  2011            8.4          9.678571
                 12 'Aaron Hernandez'    15  2011           20.5          9.678571
                 13 'Aaron Hernandez'    16  2011            3.7          9.678571
                 14 'Aaron Hernandez'    17  2011           22.4          9.678571
                 15 'Aaron Hernandez'     1  2012           12.4          8.755556
                 16 'Aaron Hernandez'     6  2012            9.0          8.755556
                 17 'Aaron Hernandez'     7  2012            5.4          8.755556
                 18 'Aaron Hernandez'    12  2012            3.6          8.755556
                 19 'Aaron Hernandez'    13  2012            9.7          8.755556
                 20 'Aaron Hernandez'    14  2012           17.8          8.755556",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```